# App crash Due to memory managment

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-management

```
#import "MYViewController.h"
#import "DataSyncHandler.h"
#import "ParentTableViewCell.h"
#import "Ayaah.h"
static NSString *ParentCellIdentifier = @"ParentTableViewCell";
@interface MYViewController ()
{
    double pinchscale;
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *twoFingerPinch;
    CGPoint buttonPosition;
    NSIndexPath *iPath;
    DBManager *bmanager;
    CGPoint p;
    UIFont *df;
    UIFont *df1;
    NSMutableArray *header;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;
   CGAffineTransform cg;
}
@end

@implementation MYViewController
@synthesize dataSource;// nsmutable array which have filled from sqlite databasedata
@synthesize ptc;// customcell 
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
       self.dataSource=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    cg=_tableView.transform;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0;
    _tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.delegate=self;
    self.tableView.dataSource=self;
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer  * recognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingerPinch:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [_tableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [self fetchmoreAyah];
   }

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    header=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 0; i<[self.dataSource count]; i++) {
                [header addObject:[@(i) stringValue]];
    }
    [self fetchmoreAyah];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)fetchmoreAyah {
       defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//custom font name and size set by user in settings and creating new font according to users desire
    df=[UIFont fontWithName:[defaults objectForKey:@"FontStyle"] size:(CGFloat)[[defaults objectForKey:@"Font"] floatValue]];
    df1=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)[[defaults objectForKey:@"Font"] floatValue]];
    self.dataSource=[[DataSyncHandler defaultHandler] fetchCompleteSurahForSelectedSurahID:self.surahId andUrduTranslatorRef:[defaults objectForKey:@"Language"] andEngTranslatorRef:[defaults objectForKey:@"Translator" ]];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.dataSource.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ParentTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ParentTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
    }
        Ayaah * ayaahObj = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [self setSubtitleForCell:cell item:ayaahObj];
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"gmii.jpg"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
        [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
        return cell;
}
- (void)setSubtitleForCell:(ParentTableViewCell *)cell item:(Ayaah *)item {
    cell.ArbiLabel.font =df;
    cell.EnglishLabel.font = df1;
    cell.urdulabl.font=df1;
    [cell.idlbl setText:item.ayaahID];
    NSDecimalNumber *someNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:item.ayaahID];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *arLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar"];
    [formatter setLocale:arLocale];
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@﴿%@﴾",item.ayaahText,[formatter stringFromNumber:someNumber]];
    [cell.ArbiLabel setText:str];
    if(![[defaults objectForKey:@"Language" ] isEqualToString:@"None"])
    {
        [cell.urdulabl setText:item.urduTranslationText];
        cell.urdulabl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
        if (![[defaults objectForKey:@"Translator" ] isEqualToString:@"None"])
        {
            [cell.EnglishLabel setText:item.englishTranslationText];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.EnglishLabel setText:@""];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (![[defaults objectForKey:@"Translator" ] isEqualToString:@"None"])
        {
            [cell.EnglishLabel setText:item.englishTranslationText];
            cell.EnglishLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            [cell.urdulabl setText:@""];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.EnglishLabel setText:@""];
            [cell.urdulabl setText:@""];
        }
    }
}

- (void)twoFingerPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if(recognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        _tableView.transform=cg;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    else
    {
        pinchscale=0.0;
      pinchscale = recognizer.scale;
       // pinchscale = round(pinchscale * 1000) / 1000.0;
    CGFloat fontSize = df.pointSize;

    if (pinchscale < 1) {
        if(fontSize>14)
        {
            _tableView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(pinchscale, pinchscale);
            pinchscale=.55;
        df=[UIFont fontWithName:[defaults objectForKey:@"FontStyle"] size:(CGFloat)[[defaults objectForKey:@"Font"] floatValue] - pinchscale];
            df1=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)[[defaults objectForKey:@"Font"] floatValue] - pinchscale];
            CGFloat FontSize = df.pointSize;
            [defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", FontSize] forKey:@"Font"];
        }
    }
    else if(pinchscale>1){
    if(fontSize<60&&fontSize>=13)
        {
            _tableView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(pinchscale, pinchscale);
            pinchscale=pinchscale/3;
          df=[UIFont fontWithName:[defaults objectForKey:@"FontStyle"] size:(CGFloat)[[defaults objectForKey:@"Font"] floatValue] + pinchscale];
            df1=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)[[defaults objectForKey:@"Font"] floatValue] + pinchscale];
            CGFloat FontSize = df.pointSize;
            [defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", FontSize] forKey:@"Font"];
        }
    }
       // [fontSize r];
    }
    //
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return header;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    for (int i = 0; i< index; i++) {
        Ayaah * ayaahObj = [dataSource objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *letterString =ayaahObj.ayaahID ;
        if ([letterString isEqualToString:title]) {
            [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
@end
```

**its consuming 100mb to 200mb when font size is 15 and when enter code here m inenter code herecreasing my font size 15 to 45 or 60 then my app crash and memory shoot from 200mb to 400mb+ and message display app crash due to memory management. am using custom cell which have 3 labels  **